# Moving from 1 view to another

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an application in which I ask a General Knowledge question. Each question is a `TextView` and solutions are shown as choices (4 buttons).

Though I am still designing, I was wondering if there is a way to move from 1 `TextView` (the question) to the next. Though, it is possible to transit from 1 activity to another (each activity becomes a question and an answer), but I am sure there might be a better way to do that.

Comment: I must clarify: I would like to transit from 1 question to another. Though I know this is possible using intents, actionlisteners and activities, I would like to know if, within a same activity, I could set the view from one to the next.

Comment: what about just changing the contents of the Buttons and the textview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a new activity for each, why not use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think i have a starter now.

Answer (score 2):

Hi You don't need to Use Activity for each Question. Instead of that you can change the text in TextView.

Use this in Button OnClick

```
           TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourid);
           textview .setText(yourQuestion)
```

I hope It helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could place your questions inside a ScrollView and when user clicks answer for question you get the y position of next question and use ScrollView scrollTo(0,y).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have great idea about that but I think you waste your design if you do that.

I have another idea, how about you create each question as an array then you can call the other  on the same activity. I think it's more compact at design. :)

for example:

```
       TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourid);
       textview .setText(Questions here!!)
```

Comment: and don't forget to vote my answer if you think it useful... :)